# FloatingActionButton sample works in Android Studio but not in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, floating-action-button

Long-time Eclipse-ADT user, and I've started looking into Android Studio since most samples on the web are now built with gradle. Now I just recently installed Android Studio on my machine and am trying out the samples from developer.android.com, specifically this one: [FloatingActionButton](http://developer.android.com/samples/FloatingActionButtonBasic/index.html?utm_campaign=lollipopsamples-1214&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)

I imported the project in Android Studio, run it on my Nexus 5, works fine. The FABs are rounded and has drop shadows and all.

Now out of curiosity I tried to build the same project in Eclipse. So I fired up Eclipse, created a new project, copy-pasted everything from the `Application` folder into their proper destinations, then run the project on the same device.

**The buttons are square.**

Looking into the code, the following lines are responsible for giving the buttons a round shape are as follows:

Under FloatingActionButton.java

```
setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            outline.setOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    });

setClipToOutline(true);
```

Now question is, why does these snippets of code work on Android Studio but not in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. The issue is that the AndroidManifest.xml that i copied over from the Application/src/main folder does not have a min SDK and a target SDK version -- both of which are defined in the build.gradle file, in the /Application directory. I added both and the FABs are now rounded with shadows and all.

Since I can't give bounty to myself, I'd give it to the answer who can explain further, or at least point to something that documents this change.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely related to which dependencies are in your project.

Using Gradle, you can configure wildcards for dependency version numbers, meaning that your project will always have the latest version of that library (for better or for worse)

With Eclipse-ANT you are most likely using manually downloaded and imported libraries, of a static version number. And the particular version you are using is compiling square buttons

Answer (score 0):

Now in AndroidStudio you can specify the most of the manifest configuration in build.gradle it will first refers to the module's build.gradle for this configs it is helpful and required for many things one i know is as follows.

Android studio and gradle gives you many new features one of them is buildtypes and flavours using which  you can create a new flavours of your one project with very much less efforts, see in eclipse you need to create a whole new project for another flavour of your project while in android studio you can do it in single project. See when you define another flavour you can also define some of the manifest properties that will apply only to that flavour like you can change project name, package name, min sdk, target sdk, version, permission and so on.

There will only will be one manifest so if you declare multiple flavours and define this kind of changes                   than build.gradle file will fetch that changes and applies to the manifest specifically for that flavour so your manifest will get updated for that flavour.